# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'x' from assembly 'x'?

Tags: c#, .net, config, typeloadexception

**I would just like to apologise by the overload of information, I just want to provide anything that could be related, I'm not sure what's happening**

> Test method DCIM_Test_1.MySQLDefTest.ConnectionStringTest threw exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DCIM_With_Test.Database.Database_MySQLDef' from assembly 'DCIM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I am getting this error when I run one of my tests, and I believe it's coming from how I re-named my Solution and Projects recently.

I renamed them all from 'DCIM_With_Test' to 'DCIM', (Changed the directories, file names etc.) but it is still causing inconsistencies here and there.

Another cause could possibly be the way the method that is causing the issue is running. I have changed the method from reading from a text file to reading from an `app.config` file and I am new to this process and XML so I could be missing a step somewhere.

Here is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=dcim;uid=root;pwd=LlmD62jL;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I am also getting three messages about app.config:

> 1. Could not find the schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime'.
> 2. Could not find the schema information for the attribute 'version'.
> 3. Could not find the schema information for the attribute 'sku'.

Here is the method being tested **NOTE: The OLD METHOD runs fine, but the test still throws the exception, but the NEW METHOD doesn't work at all.**

```
public static string GetConnectionString()
{
    /* OLD METHOD
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\setupfile.txt");
    mySqlConnectionString = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    rdr.Close();
    */

    // NEW METHOD    
    mySqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    return mySqlConnectionString;
}
```

And here is the test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ConnectionStringTest()
{
    int actual = 0;
    int expected = 1;
    Database_MySQLDef.GetConnectionString();
    if (Database_MySQLDef.mySqlConnectionString != "")
    {
        actual = 1;
    }
    else { actual = 0; }

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: What's inside Database_MySQLDef static constructor (even implicit)? Run same code in debug and you'll see what's wrong (or inspect TypeLoadException properties for details).

Comment: Does your test assembly have an app.config?

Comment: Sounds like stale assemblies, try cleaning the sln.

Comment: @mikez my test project doesn't but my main project does. Not sure if that's the same thing?

Comment: @khellang I hit 'Clean Solution' then 'Build Solution' and still no effect. All the messages remain and the Test still fails.

Comment: @Adriano not sure if this is what you're referring to but this class is just a list of static and constant strings, the method `GetConnectionString()` is the only method in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does your test assembly have an app.config?
>
> my test project doesn't but my main project does. Not sure if that's the same thing?

No, they aren't. I suspect what is happening is that `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` is going to the test assembly's app config (this is MSTest's behavior, I believe), not the your main project's app config. Then, because that doesn't exist, you are getting an Exception thrown in a static initializer or static constructor and this is wrapped by the TypeLoadException.

A simple way to solve this is to just add an app.config to your test assembly. Then you can put in whatever connection string you need for the tests.

Comment: ok, so that would explain the `app.config` conflicts, but why does the `old method` fail too? it was working fine before I started renaming my project. Do you know much about that?

Comment: @Ben Does it throw exactly the same exception? I wasn't sure whether you meant threw the same exception or failed the test.

Comment: yes the same exception is thrown when I use either method

Comment: @Ben ok, well yea its the assembly name change. It sounds like a stale assembly is being found by the tests. I would manually clean whatever output directories you have. How are you referencing the production project? via a project reference or a reference to a dll file?

Comment: I believe it's just by reference. `using DCIM;`? Which is why I'm confused by the `Could not load type 'DCIM_With_Test'`.

Comment: @Ben I would do this first. Select the reference in the test project's References list. Go to the Properties Window (View > Properties Window). Look at the value of "Path". What is it? Is it where you expect it to be getting the dll from? You should probably delete that whole directory and rebuild. If it still doesn't work, is there a post build step that copies files around? You are getting an old version of the DCIM dll from somewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51631/discussion-between-ben-and-mike-z)