# The test assembly '*.dll' cannot be loaded. Error details: Could not find file *.dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, dll

**UPDATE:** I've figured out that every time I run a test, a new folder is created (Benjamin_C12LPCRE 'date' 'time') but the dll is not being *created* where as I thought it was originally just *missing*.

What I have done:

1. Removed and re-added the reference to the Main Project (DCIM) in the Test Project
2. Removed and re-added the reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`
3. Built, Re-Built and Cleaned (not necessarily in that order) the Main and Test Projects, and the Entire Solution
4. Deleted all "obj" and "bin" folders in whole solution.
5. Added `[DeploymentItem("DCIM.dll")]` attribute to the Test Project, both before the `[TestClass()]` and `[TestMethod()]` declarations

**So how do I make sure all the necessary files are being created properly?**

*Original Question:*

Yesterday, my tests were running fine, I recently did a project re-name, which led to some confusion with some of the tests, but now none of my tests are working, and they all show this error:

> The test assembly 'C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DCIM\TestResults\Benjamin_C12LPCRE 2014-04-29 11_57_58\Out\DCIM Test.dll' cannot be loaded. Error details: Could not find file 'C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DCIM\TestResults\Benjamin_C12LPCRE 2014-04-29 11_57_58\Out\DCIM Test.dll'.

I checked the file path and lo and behold, no dll.

**Should there be? Is there a way to fix this?**

The Test project is in the same solution as the Main project, and as I said, I recently renamed my project which was causing some errors which I have asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334933/system-typeloadexception-could-not-load-type-x-from-assembly-y)

Comment: As a sanity check, have you removed and re-added the reference?

Comment: @GrantThomas I did, but no avail. I even removed all of the test project, removed all references to it and deleted the Test project, then re-created it and still no luck

Comment: If on your project you do a right click -> properties, is the Assembly Name matching your project name and output type set as Class Library?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Yes all that is correct.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault When you say "Assembly name matching your project name", do you mean Assembly and project name = "DCIM Test" (Test project) or "DCIM" (Original Project)?

Comment: @Ben Meant the assembly name from the textbox in the properties page and your project name directly from the Solution Explorer. I've used ReSharper's rename feature a couple times before and had problems with references, renaming the assembly (because R# only renamed the project) fixed it.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Oh ok, I did all mine manually so everything matches up, but it's still saying `Can't find 'Test Results\DCIM.dll` :(

Comment: But if the message says "Can't find 'Test Results\DCIM.dll", then it's looking for the old project. Have you checked if the "using" clause on your test class is trying to use the old project?

Comment: @NahuelI. When I first started renaming things that was causing issues, but I changed `using DCIM_With_Test` (old) to `using DCIM` (new) and it was running ok for a while, but now it's not..?

Comment: When you build your project (not the test project), what is the name of the assembly generated on the Debug folder?

Comment: @NahuelI. "DCIM". But there is a "DCIM_With_Test.vshost.exe" and a "DCIM_With_Test.vshost.exe.config" as well as a DCIM variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try two things:

- delete all "obj" and "bin" folders in whole solution (they will be recreated on build)
- add `[DeploymentItem("DCIM.dll")]` attribute in your test project, just before `[TestMethod]` attribute (you can also put it before `[TestClass]` attribute

Then rebuild everything and try again.

---

**EDIT:**

Answered by author in comments: 
*I opened the 'output' window to see if I could follow what was happening and something strange was occurring on build. Even though I had both projects selected to build, it was skipping over the test project in the output window. So I un-ticked both projects to build, re-built the solution, then re-ticked both projects and it's working again. Very odd.*

Since the solution came up in comments and it isn't mine, I mark this answer as 'community wiki'.

Comment: Didn't work. Is there a possibility something's gone wrong with Visual Studio? Maybe a re-install might be in order?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem? I mean create simple console app project with one method in it, test project, perform tests, similar rename. If the problem occurs, post step by step how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: No good. I tried to recreate it but the new project runs as smoothly as ever.

Comment: So there's clearly something wrong in the project's settings somewhere.

Comment: Maybe look into project sources: open "DCIM.csproj" and "DCIM Test.csproj" in Notepad (I prefer Notepad++) and search for "DCIM". Check if there's nothing wrong (for example: wrong path, old reference, anything connected with the old name of project) - sometimes *.csproj file may contain some rubbish that is not displayed in Visual Studio. You can also check your *.sln file in Notepad.

Comment: Still nothing! I should let you know that each time a test is run, it creates a folder and in it there are two file (DCIM.exe and DCIM.pdb). It's looking for the DCIM.dll but there is no DCIM.dll anywhere in the entire project folder?

Comment: DCIM.exe? It's strange that DCIM Test requires *.dll file and it compiles to DCIM Test.dll without it.

Anyway, if DCIM shouldn't be application, change project type in DCIM project properties to Class Library and remove and add refrence to DCIM project in DCIM Tet project.

If it is an application, make sure if the project type in DCIM project properties is correct (e.g. Console Application). Change [DeploymentItem]  from "DCIM.dll" to "DCIM.exe", remove and add refrence to DCIM project in DCIM Test project. In short, try to make sure that DCIM Test will look for DCIM.exe and not DCIM.dll.

Comment: I'd also check the TestSettings. In Visual Studio, Tests menu and "Select Active Test Settings" - select none. You can also review your tests settings (if there are any active) by editing them.

If there's a *.vsmdi file in your solution folder, you can rename or delete it and then check if tests work.

And when you checked your *.csproj sources in notepad - are there `<Reference>`-nodes to DCIM project or `ProjectReference`-nodes? There should be ProjectReferences to projects from your solution.

Comment: I found it! I opened the 'output' window to see if I could follow what was happening and something strange was occurring on build. Even though I had both projects selected to build, it was skipping over the test project in the output window. So I un-ticked both projects to build, re-built the solution, then re-ticked both projects and it's working again. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when there was no free space on the disk of a remote machine. Cleaning the space fixed the issue.